# how to timeout requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-gps, android-looper

When no GPS fix found, the code is getting stuck indefinitely in the looper.
I want to add a timeout so that if there is no GPS fix found, it should come out of the looper and execute the remaining part of the code.

I will really appreciate if you can help me in fixing this issue.

```
public class service_task extends Service {

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    private class ServerThread extends Thread implements LocationListener {

        public LocationManager locationManager = null;
        public String msg = "default";
        public String id = "default";
        private Location mLocation = null;
        public Socket socket = null;
        public int serviceid;


        public ServerThread(LocationManager locationManager, int startid) {
            super("UploaderService-Uploader");
            this.locationManager = locationManager;
            this.serviceid=startid;          
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public void run() {

            
            Looper.prepare();
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Looper.loop();

            
            if (mLocation!=null) {
                msg = "GPS data:" + mLocation;
            }else{
                msg ="No GPS data";
            }

            stopSelf(serviceid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLocation = location;
            Log.d("D", String.valueOf(location));
            this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }


    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        
        Log.d("D", "startcommand");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ServerThread thread = new ServerThread(locationManager,startId);
        thread.start();
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Handler` that uses your `Looper`: `handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());`
Then use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)` to post a new `Runnable` that cancels location updates and quits your `Looper` after a given delay.